It is possible to detect the tab character '\t' in a string?
In Python, I'd like to see if the tab character "\t" exists in a string, and not the actual tab itself. Is there a way to do that? The following code did not work for me:
def detector(a):

    detect = False

    for i in a:
        if i == '\t':
            detect = True
    if detect == True:
        print('tab character detected')
    else:
        print('no tab character detected')

detector(input())

for example, when I type "Python\t" into the input, the code outputs "no tab character detected", while the character '\t' is clearly in the string.
I've tried using raw string (if I == r'\t') but that did not work.

A tab character is a single character, the actual tab itself; the "" followed by a "t" pair of characters you're looking for, which is a way of representing a tab to be visible in a string, is called an escape sequence.

If you type Python\t when prompted for input it will store Python\\t, which doesn't have a single character tab in it.

I think that input() ignores the tab key when pressed. Your function works ok if you write: detector('Python\t')

This question is similar to: How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?. It's asking about file path, but the issue and answer are the same.

Aside: don't use input as a variable name, it shadows the input() function.

@BTables "it will store Python\\t" - No, it will store Python\t, but it will represent it as 'Python\\t'.

@quamrana "I think that input() ignores the tab key when pressed" - It might depend on the terminal. Mine doesn't ignore it.

@Chris str isn't an improvement over input since it's also a builtin. For this example, you can just use s instead, short for "string".

I'm not sure how to answer this question since the question is invalid (r'\t' isn't one character, as others have said), but there are certainly some related questions that should help: Why do backslashes appear twice? (talks about data vs representation) and Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method? (how to check for a character sequence in a string, if that's what you actually want; or even if it's not, using in saves writing a loop)

@wjandrea gotcha

Your function is fine. The question may really be, how does one input a literal tab character from the terminal? That has nothing to do with Python.
